# Sampling Distribution; Statistics. Please verify my answer

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

Professor earns average $ \text{\$} 65,500$  per year with standard deviation of $\text{\$}3,500$.

Random sample of $64$.

a. Describe sampling distribution of sample mean $\bar{x}$  of average salary of these professors.

Since sample mean is the same as population mean, I said it is unbiased, since its mean is true to its parameter.

b. within what limit would you expect sample mean to fall with probability $0.95$

I used $1.96\text{SE} = 1.96\times 3,500/\sqrt{65}$ = $857.5$

therefore $95\text{% }$to fall within $\pm 857.5$ of the mean

c. obtain probability that $\bar{x}$ is greater than $66,000$

I used  $(66,000 - 65,500) / 3,500 = 0.1428$
and gotten $Z$ value of $0.5557$

$1-0.5557 = 0.4443$

therefore $0.4443$ chance that $\bar{x}$ is greater than $66,000$

Can anyone shed some light if I have gotten these questions correctly.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**(a)** I agree with your answer (plus what David said).
It is unbiased where $\mathbb E(\overline{x})=\mu$.

**(b)** It should be **$1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$**

I.e.  $1.96 \frac{3500}{\sqrt{64}} = 857.5$ ($65$ is probably a typo as you have the correct answer.)

**(c)** As the previous answerer has pointed out, your denominator needs to be changed from $\sigma$ to $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.

$Z= \frac{\overline{x}-\mu}{\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}}}$

$Z= \frac{66,000-65,500}{\frac{3500}{\sqrt{64}}}$

$Z≈1.143$

We now need to look for $\mathbb P(Z>1.143)$

If we want to use tables, we need to note the following:

Since we can only get $\varPhi(1.14)$ or  $\varPhi(1.15)$ from our tables, I would suggest that you interpolate the value so that you can get an approximation of  $\varPhi(1.145)$ which is closer to $1.143$.

- $1-\varPhi(1.14)=  1-0.87206 = 0.12794$
- $1-\varPhi(1.15)=  1-0.87493 = 0.12507$

∴ $\mathbb P(\overline{x} > 66,000)≈ \frac{0.12794+0.12507}{2}$

Comment: For some reason, the formatting of my x̄ messed up, it is supposed to represent x bar.

Comment: Use MathJax/LaTeX to format the math. Then you get $\bar x,$ no problem. (Also you can write square roots using $\sqrt n$ rather than having to spell out "sqrt" all the time.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit Caran-d'Ache, I will try to use MathJax for whenever I next answer a question.

Answer (score 1):

I think for part (a), a complete description of "sampling distribution of sample mean" would include the *standard error* (that is, the standard deviation of $\bar x$) in addition to the mean of $\bar x$. A mean is not a distribution.
(Technically neither is a mean and a standard error/deviation, but I'm supposing you are
allowed to assume a normal distribution without saying so.)

For part (b), you correctly computed the standard error 
(except for typing "$65$" when you apparently meant $64$) 
and used it to find the correct interval of salaries.

For part (c) you apparently forgot that you're dealing with the distribution of the *sample mean* rather than the distribution of the population, and you gave the probability that a random individual $x$ is greater than $66,000.$
This is part of the reason why I think part (a) asked for the *distribution*
rather than just the *mean* of $\bar x$; you were meant to remember that
$95$% of the time $\bar x$ will fall within $1.96$ *standard errors* of the mean,
not just within $1.96$ *standard deviations* (using the standard deviation of
the original population).

Answer (score 0):

$a)$: True.

$b)$: It should be $\sqrt{64}$, but correct value $857.5$.

$c)$: Wrong. It should be $P\left(\bar{x} > 66,000\right) = P\left(z > \dfrac{66,000-65,500}{\dfrac{3,500}{\sqrt{64}}}\right)$ = ....